# Relative selction .Xvalues (Charts)

Tags: vba, excel

1st: The selection of .XValues/.Values works only if I hardcode the cells (which I don't want to) and not the way I did it.

2nd: Every 2nd time that I run the code, there are already some series when I add the chart so I end up with more series than I want to.

```
Sub AddChart()

Dim ch As Chart
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Data")

Set ch = CHARTS.Add2   

With ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = ws.Range("B1")
    .XValues = ws.Range("B18", Range("B18").End(xlDown))
    .Values = ws.Range("C18", Range("C18").End(xlDown))
End With   

End Sub
```

Comment: Check if series exists first and if does do not do .NewSeries and for .XValues = myRange variable instead of hardcoding so you use a range variable which you can change

Comment: How many series do you actually want and what are you actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to update a single series as when you add new data in the sheet?

Comment: @QHarr I declared `Set xRange = ws.Range("B18", Range("B18").End(xlDown))` and then used at `.XValues = xRange` and it works. I want to build the graph out of a worksheet.

Comment: That still isn't clarifying for me..."build out of a sheet". Don't mean to be difficult. In my answer below I have tried to outline some of the tools at your disposal. Get back to me with any questions and [edit] any new information about your task into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a few things:

1. You are adding a chart sheet
2. NewSeries is adding a new series
3. When you say you don't want to hard code what do you mean? You can use a variable to assign to the existing series.

I would propose that you separate the chart creation from the chart updating

So in the following we have a create chart sub to create the chart:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateChart()

Dim ch As Chart
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
Set ch = Charts.Add2

With ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = ws.Range("B1")
    .XValues = ws.Range("Xseries")
    .Values = ws.Range("Yseries")
End With

End Sub
```

And then we have an update chart function that works with the existing chart sheet. Now depending on how you want to update the XValues and Values you could  simply pass a range variable as the new assignment e.g.

```
 ch.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = myRangeVariable
```

In the case I am giving you can use a 2 dynamic named ranges. This means whenever you run the update sub any new rows in the source columns will be picked up and added to the chart.

The dynamic series are added to name manager, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and there is one for the X series and one for the Y:

Xseries

```
=OFFSET(Data!$B$18,0,0,COUNT(Data!$B$18:$B$1048576),1)
```

Yseries

```
=OFFSET(Data!$C$18,0,0,COUNT(Data!$C$18:$C$1048576),1)
```

**Dynamic series in name manager**

[image: Dynamic series in name manager]

Code to update chart (could be associated with a button)

```
Sub UpdateChart()

    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Set ch = wb.Charts("Chart1") 'change as appropriate

    ch.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range("Xseries")
    ch.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range("Yseries")

End Sub
```

Now, if you were simply concerned with having a chart that picked up newly added rows of data you could skip VBA and just use the dynamic series direct with the chart

You would edit the existing chart series and for the Y values put

```
=Book1!Yseries
```

And for the X values put

```
=Book1!Xseries
```

`Book1` being replaced with whatever your workbook name is.